# Number of solutions to equations in finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, character-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and that $E$ is an equation of the form $x_1 x_2 ... x_n = e$, where each $x_i$ is in the set of symbols $\{x, y, x^{-1}, y^{-1}\}$.

> Is it always true that the number of ordered pairs $(g, h)$ of elements of $G$ satisfying $E$ is a multiple of $|G|$?

I know that it is true in many cases and I can't find any counterexamples. Does anybody know a simple counterexample, or a suitable reference for this question?

Comment: @M.Vinay Thanks for that - it looks much better!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  This is a special case of results in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2824.pdf

Comment: Indeed, it appears to be a special case of results in Louis Solomon, The solution of equations in groups, Arch. Math. 20 (1969) 241-247, MR0249497 (40 #2742).